# panasonic sd-audio format, does it exist?

Tags: audio, mp3, sd-card

I was wondering if anyone knows about sd-audio.

I've a panasonic strada car audio head (from japan, in japanese, so I cannot understand much).

It has sd card plugin, and menu item called sd-audio. When I load mp3 files in the folder and insert in car player, nothing happens some notice comes saying what I don't know.

Than it hit me, maybe there is a difference between audio on SD and sd-audio, similar to how burning data cd with mp3 is different to audio-cd.

IS my hunch correct? how do I create sd-audio card?

Everything I search seems to come up in japanesse :S

I could only find this: https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/sd_apps/sd-audio/

Comment: Generally a SD slot is for the purpose of turning it into a MP3 player. First are you able to create a MP3 Data only (not audio) CD and play it in the CD parts? then it is likely a MP3 playing device. First thing that comes to mind for me would be FileSystem , you could try fat16 First to test, then Fat32 if that worked (or just fat32 and hope that it begins to work like that, and you dont have to step back further). Next thing might be too many items on a root, to many items per folder, or it expecting no folders? It is unlikely to have a "book".

Comment: "nothing happens some notice comes saying what I don't know." - take a picture and see if Google lens translates it.

Answer (score 1):

There's very little information of SD Audio available on the Internet, due to their low popularity outside of Japan. In the following paragraph I'll put what I've learnt so far, in case of someone reads this.

Panasonic SD Audio format does exist, though largely remained in the Japanese market. Panasonic used the technology on its line of portable music players (some early models were marketed as "e-wear"), "multimedia" cameras (with music playback capability), car stereos (take Strada unit here for example), Japanese feature phones, and some component systems as well. It even made its way onto one of Technic's turntables (SL-DZ1200). Long story short, much like Sony's SonicStage, the software (SD-Jukebox) will encrypt the track with its propietary DRM before transfering it to the SD card, preventing any further modification or copy.

Panasonic supported the software well into 2010s, until in early 2018 when they shut down the activation service. However, as of 2023, one can still prepare a SD Audio card with one of the following softwares. Most of these are basically standalone installers of SD-Jukebox that don't require any form of activation.

1. SD Jukebox v2.4

Compatible with Windows 98/2k/XP and strangely also works on Windows 7. Does not require a propietary SD reader. No support for SDHC.

2. SD Jukebox v5.1 LE
   https://archive.org/details/panasonic-sd-jukebox-v-5.1

Compatible with Windows 2k/XP but requires Panasonic's SD reader or SD Audio players. No support for SDHC.

3. Real(One) player for Panasonic
   https://archive.org/details/real-one-panasonic

Real(One) player with Panasonic-specific plugin that was originally bundled with SD75/80 ("e-wears"). Confirmed to work on Windows 10 but requires Panasonic's SD reader or SD Audio players. No support for SDHC.

4. SD Jukebox V6.8 LE (Japanese only)
   https://archive.org/details/panasonic-sd-jukebox-6.8-le

An upgraded version of SD-Jukebox that supports SDHC (on selected models). Unfortunately, it requires region-spoofing software in order to install properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a similar unit.

I think you're right that "sd-audio" is a specific format of card and content, including copyright protection, but all I can find is the [standard](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/sd-standard-overview/application-formats/sd-audio/) from the SD Association.

While I can't get the files to play off the SD card (if that is even possible) I found the trick is to copy them to the HDD (assuming your model includes one) and play from there.

You can use the translate mode of google lens, or camera mode of google translate apps to see what the options and messages are in english.

There should be an option somewhere to copy files off the SD card to the HDD as per [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbWYmOJeynU) video. I have a similar unit to this and mine was in the settings menu (press menu button then swipe up and left).

Make sure the card is in the correct format (Fat32 works for me), your files are in a matching folder structure and the correct format (I believe mp3 is the only option).